# regular expression not between alphanumeric

Tags: regex, r, parsing, variables

I would like to identify the string "mystring" in a text (actually a R code), but ensuring that it is a variable name:

- it should not be part of a longer variable such as "thisismystring" or "mystringisnice". I guess this can be done by excluding (?!([[:alnum:]]){1}) before and after "mystring"?
- It can however be at the beginning of a line (such as "\nmystring") so we have to be careful about this type of exception

What is the best approach for that?

Edit: unit test

```
pattern = "\\bmystring\\b"
identical(grepl(pattern = pattern, 
            x = c("thisismystring","mystringisnice","\nmystring", "mystring", "mystring=", "mystring(", " mystring","mystring\n", "6mystring", "mystring0", "= mystring(", "=mystring", 
"hop
mystring")),
      c(FALSE,          FALSE,           TRUE,         TRUE,        TRUE,        TRUE,         TRUE,       TRUE,        FALSE, FALSE,       TRUE,          TRUE,    TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `\b` (word boundary) token:

```
\\bmystring\\b
```

unit test

```
pattern = "\\bmystring\\b"
`==`(grepl(pattern = pattern, 
                x = c("thisismystring","mystringisnice","\nmystring", "mystring", "mystring=", "mystring(", " mystring","mystring\n", "6mystring", "mystring0", "= mystring(", "=mystring", 
                      "hop
                      mystring")),
          c(FALSE,          FALSE,           TRUE,         TRUE,        TRUE,        TRUE,         TRUE,       TRUE,        FALSE, FALSE,       TRUE,          TRUE,    TRUE))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this. unfortunately doesn't pass my unit tests (See in the question).